# Find intersecting dates

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, count

Can somebody help me with next problem. I have MS Access table, lets say with my employees, and for each one of them I have start and end date of their vacation:

```
Name    begin       end
John    1.3.2021.   15.3.2021.
Robert  6.3.2021.   8.3.2021.
Lisa    13.3.2021.  16.3.2021.
John    1.4.2021.   3.4.2021.
Robert  2.4.2021.   2.4.2021.
Lisa    15.5.2021.  23.5.2021.
Lisa    5.6.2021.   15.6.2021.
```

How to get the result with number of employees which are absent from work per each date from the table (dates which are included into intervals begin-end). For example:

```
1.3.2021. 1     '>>>only John
2.3.2021. 1     '>>>only John
3.3.2021. 1     '>>>only John
4.3.2021. 1     '>>>only John
5.3.2021. 1     '>>>only John
6.3.2021. 2     '>>>John and Robert
7.3.2021. 2     '>>>John and Robert
...
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union` to combine the tables and a correlated subquery:

```
select dte,
       (select count(*)
        from t
        where d.dte between t.[begin] and t.[end]
       ) as cnt
from (select [begin] as dte
      from t
      union 
      select [end]
      from t
     ) d;
```

Comment: Thank you! This was quick :). It's seems very close to solution but not all dates are in the result. For example I get result for 1.3.2021. and the next is for 6.3.2021.

Comment: @Mario . . . Your question says:  "per each date from the table ".  If you need the between dates, then you'll need a calendar table as well.

Comment: Hello, I ment only dates which are defined by intervals (begin-end) like in my example result. Can those dates somehow be retrieved from those intervals instead from calendar table? I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Mario . . . Not really in MS Access.  You need a calendar table.

Comment: OK. I made a calendar table and adjust the last part of your sql statement and it works - so thank you very much!